# How to check order factor variable in R

Tags: r, variables, refactoring

I have factor variables in a data frame. I want some of them to be  ordered (such as education) and some of them unordered  (such as sex).

I create some of the variables and some get created automatically.

Is there a way to check that? Maybe using `str()` or some other method?

Comment: This is unclear. Please provide an example.

Comment: If you're unsure how to do that, consider reading [ask] and [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `str` will show you if the factors are ordered, yes. It will call it `Ord.factor`.

Comment: Thank David Arenburg and if it not ordered what it will show?

Comment: It will just show `Factor`

Answer (score 1):

So after long searched i realize it simply answer all my factor was unordered. ordered factor sign by greater then sign (>) and unordered there is no sign between levels as shown in this  code

```
> orderEduc[1:6]
[1] high        junior-high high        elementary  high        junior-high
Levels: elementary < junior-high < high < academic

> finalDF$eduction[1:6]
[1] high        junior-high high        elementary  high        junior-high
Levels: elementary junior-high high academic
```

one web page that help me understand was http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/factor_variables.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this for checking class of each variable for `data.frame`.

```
iris$Sepal.Length <- as.ordered(iris$Sepal.Length)
sapply(iris, class)

# $Sepal.Length
# [1] "ordered" "factor" 
# 
# $Sepal.Width
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $Petal.Length
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $Petal.Width
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $Species
# [1] "factor"
```

Comment: but can i distinguish between ordered factor and not ordered one?

Comment: There's an extra class `ordered` for ordered factor.

Answer (score 0):

The function `is.ordered()` returns TRUE when its argument is an ordered factor and FALSE otherwise.

Following the example by [@leouyi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232542/10647267):

```
iris$Sepal.Length <- is.ordered(iris$Sepal.Length)

sapply(iris, is.ordered)

Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species    
        TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
```